# The best way to join in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, join, comparison

I was working with the first method below, but then I found the second and want to know the difference and which is best.

What is the difference between:

```
from a in this.dataContext.reglements
join b in this.dataContext.Clients on a.Id_client equals b.Id 
select...
```

and

```
from a in this.dataContext.reglements
from b in this.dataContext.Clients
where a.Id_client == b.Id 
select...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I created a test case to test out the difference, and in your scenerio it turns out they are the same.

My test example used AdventureWorks but basically there is an association between

> Products->CategoryId->Categories

```
var q = (
    from p in Products
    from c in Categories
        where p.CategoryID==c.CategoryID
    select p
);

q.ToList();
```

Produces this SQL:

```
SELECT [t0].[ProductID], [t0].[ProductName], [t0].[CategoryID]
    FROM [Products] AS [t0], [Categories] AS [t1]
WHERE [t0].[CategoryID] = ([t1].[CategoryID])
```

---

```
var q2 = (
    from p in Products 
    join c in Categories 
        on p.CategoryID equals c.CategoryID
    select p);

q2.ToList();
```

Produces this sql:

```
SELECT [t0].[ProductID], [t0].[ProductName], [t0].[CategoryID]
FROM [Products] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN [Categories] AS [t1] ON [t0].[CategoryID] = ([t1].[CategoryID])
```

Comment: Wouldn't the second translate to an ANSI style join? Why would it be done in memory? That's valid SQL as well, no?

Comment: Are you certain of this? There's no particular reason that L2S couldn't generate a multi-part `FROM` clause in SQL.

Comment: @Esteban: That is not an "ANSI style" join; that's a legacy-style join, as the `JOIN` clause was introduced in the ANSI SQL-92 spec nearly 10 years ago.

Comment: @Adam: Thanks for the clarification. So "pre-ANSI style" would have been correct, right?

Comment: @Adam setting up a linq2sql test now to see the output.  I did one with data services and it did a select many, and then a where.

Comment: @Esteban: No, they're both "ANSI style" :) Both syntaxes are legal and valid ANSI SQL, though the multi-part `FROM` (the older style) is, as far as I know it, deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between these two syntaxes will be in the way they are translated into SQL.  You can trace Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL to determine the SQL:

LINQ to SQL: http://www.reflectionit.nl/Blog/PermaLinkcba15978-c792-44c9-aff2-26dbcc0da81e.aspx

Check the resulting SQL to determine if there are any differences that could affect performance.